# How to cancel pressed state for FloatingActionButton after moving finger out of its area?

Tags: android, android-support-library, floating-action-button, android-support-design

Recently I updated support design library to 24.2.0. I found that in this version, for any `FloatingActionButton`, if I long press it and then move my finger out of its area, it will still remain pressed state(showing ripple color and keeping larger elevation). How can I let it be normal state again?

Here is an example of my `FloatingActionButton`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="56dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:src="@drawable/act_add"
    app:elevation="6dp"
    app:borderWidth="0dp"
    app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"/>
```

Comment: Post code of floating button.

Comment: @ShabbirDhangot I added the code. However, I've tried to change its attributes and then I thought that all `FloatingActionButton`s will suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue of the design support library. Android bug was opened at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218956 with several workarounds submitted.  The following is another workaround that I am using inside `onCreate` (where `fab` is the `FloatingActionButton`), to cancel the pressed state upon release of touch :

```
fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action = motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                view.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        view.setPressed(false);
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

(Somehow calling `setPressed(false)` directly in the handler caused the click event not to trigger in some cases)